# Bluetoothctl stops advertising after quit

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to create a BLE-server. For this I use bluetoothctl with these commands:

```
menu advertise
name MyDevice
back
advertise on
menu gatt
register-service 8733587e-8f8a-11ee-b9d1-0242ac120002
yes
register-characteristic 0x0001 broadcast
0x0001
register-characteristic 0x0002 write
0x0001
register-characteristic 0x0003 write
0x0001
register-characteristic 0x0004 write
0x0001
register-characteristic 0x0005 read
0x0001
register-application
```

After them I can connect to my device with a phone. But if I quit from bluetoothctl - I can't connect again and previous connection disconnects.
I tried to do it with bash-script like this:

```
bluetoothctl << EOF
*commands here*
```

But it quits from bluetoothctl automatically and I can't connect too. How to do this in a right way? Thanks in advance.